# Would it make sense to use the `:link` pseudo selector in combination with a class selector?

Tags: html, css

To select all the links that have not yet been visited we can use `a:link`.  Suppose we used a class based implementation to style links like this:

```
.Link {
   ...
}
```

And we then apply this to anchor elements to style them like this:

```
<a class="Link">..</a>
```

Would it make sense to also implement `.Link:link {}`, while also implementing `.Link:visited {}`, `.Link:hover {}`, `.Link:active {}`.  In seems that in this context `.Link:link {}` and just plain `.Link {}` do the same thing?

Comment: Seems like a bit of a verbose way to go about it, you would have to apply those classes to *all* links, and unless you've got a dynamic way to do this, it's going to be an arduous task. You could use `a:not(:visited)` as well and that should also apply to all links not yet visited. If anything, using a class and pseudo-selector combination does give you more specificity though, which should help over-qualify or unset default/vendor styles.

Comment: It's for a link component - https://github.com/superflycss/component-link - it allows users to override variables, create modifiers, etc. for links that should have customized styling ... more info in general here https://github.com/superflycss/superflycss

Comment: I think the answer to your question title is "yes, sometimes". In your more complicated specific example where you are implementing `.Link:visited`, etc., I don't think you would need `.Link:link`, you'd just use `.Link` - especially if you want to set multiple style properties where only some of those properties are overridden by `.Link:visited` or `.Link:active`.

Comment: You say, "In seems that in this context `.Link:link {}` and just plain `.Link {}` do the same thing?" but in the example you gave, that is not the case. The `a` element in the example is not a link, so it won't match a `.Link:link` selector.

Comment: IIUC the pseudo selector attaches itself to the class selector.  For example `.Link:visited` targets all links that have been visited.